# Create multiple partitions without being prompted on Ubuntu CLI

Tags: ubuntu, partition

I am trying on Ubuntu to programmatically create 2 partitions on the same volume and I want to do that automatically without being prompted.

Edit:
I managed to do that with `parted`:

```bash
parted -a optimal $EXTRA_DISK mklabel gpt
parted -a optimal $EXTRA_DISK mkpart primary 0% 40%
parted -a optimal $EXTRA_DISK mkpart primary 40% 100%
```

Comment: So what's your question exactly? Have you done any research into tools that could do that? I don't have any experience with this myself, but a quick google turned up this, which looks promising: [fdisk - partition in single line - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/q/258152/403609)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sgdisk` command.

```
sgdisk -n partition_number:start_size:end_size /dev/sdb
```

Example usage:
If you run the below command, this will create a partition /dev/sdb1 with size 25GB.

```
sgdisk -n 1:0:25G /dev/sdb
```

Output:

```
root@host:/# lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0     7:0    0  55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2409
loop2     7:2    0  61.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1518
loop3     7:3    0    47M  1 loop /snap/snapd/16010
loop4     7:4    0  67.8M  1 loop /snap/lxd/22753
loop5     7:5    0    48M  1 loop /snap/snapd/16778
loop6     7:6    0  55.6M  1 loop /snap/core18/2566
loop7     7:7    0  63.2M  1 loop /snap/core20/1623
loop8     7:8    0 296.5M  1 loop /snap/google-cloud-cli/68
loop9     7:9    0 296.7M  1 loop /snap/google-cloud-cli/70
sda       8:0    0    10G  0 disk 
├─sda1    8:1    0   9.9G  0 part /
├─sda14   8:14   0     4M  0 part 
└─sda15   8:15   0   106M  0 part /boot/efi
sdb       8:16   0   375G  0 disk 
├─sdb1    8:17   0    20G  0 part
```

Once the paritition is created, you can mount to where ever location/path needed.